# Why are error bars used instead of error blobs or error rectangles?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

In reporting experimental results, it is common to use error bars to communicate uncertainty in measurement of the quantity represented by the y-axis.

But, usually, there would also be uncertainty in measurement of the quantity represented by the x-axis.

However, I have rarely seen that being shown on a graph throughout academia and research community.

Why is it so? Is there any merit in showing error rectangles instead of error bars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s perfectly possible to use error bars on the x axis as well as the y, so the error bars look like a cross. Rectangles or blobs aren’t normally used because they would obscure the point in the plot corresponding to the mean value.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also throw some light on why that isn't the norm?

Comment: I’m not an experimentalist, but it is probably because in many cases the value on the $x$ axis is known to such a high precision that its error bars would not be visible.